# SQL: How to join two columns in a specific way?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an Oracle Database and I am new to SQL in general.

I have a table with data and month columns. After filtering the data I have just a few rows left. But I want to get two columns: 1-st column with 12 months listed (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) and second column with values from original data (if exist) or zeroes.

F.e.: Original data:

```
MONTH     VALUE
  9        96
```

What I want:

```
MONTH     VALUE
  1         0
  2         0
  3         0
  4         0
  5         0
  6         0
  7         0
  8         0
  9         96
  10        0
  11        0
  12        0
```

I have already tried to use join and union all functions but it didn't work out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bro enjoy...

```
select months.month ,original_data.VALUE 
from original_data
Right JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) months(month) on
months.month = original_data.MONTH

order by months.month --optional
```

Comment: The idea is really good. Thank you. But I am getting an error message: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Comment: I guess it has something to do with months.month

Comment: This syntax tested on MSSQL. Which SQL are you using?

Comment: I think it needs to convert as oracle's syntax.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL

Comment: Can you post complete error. 
The idea is really good. Thank you. But I am getting an error message: ORA-00903: invalid table name ...?

Comment: OK, now I am done. The problem was with a syntax. To create a list of values in Oracle SQL you have to use something like this: table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) monate. Afterwards I connect my data table with created list of values (1-12 for "Months" and null for "Values") using UNION ALL function.

Answer (score 1):

First generate a sequence of 12 months number then use left join

```
select monthNo, coalesce(Value,0) as value from
(
SELECT 1 MonthNo
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)A left join originaltable b on A.monthNo=b.month
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what are you looking for?

```
WITH tab AS(SELECT LEVEL AS m , null as value  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12)
, tab2 AS(SELECT 9 as m, 96 as VALUE FROM DUAL)

select t1.m
      ,coalesce(t2.value,0) as value
from tab t1
left join tab2 t2 on t1.m = t2.m
order by 1
```